# Como listar no Windows Explorer o diretório www do Linux/Ubuntu que roda no Subsistema Windows para Linux(WSL) do Windows 10?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, www

Preciso listar os arquivos que estão em `var/www` do Ubuntu que roda no WSL, para poder realizar uma cópia de arquivo. Como fazer para visualiza-los pelo Windows Explorer para que uma aplicação que roda no Windows copie tal arquivo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Primeiramente, não é recomendado manipular essas pastas no Windows
>   Explorer. Se você deseja copiar, mover, editar ou apagar arquivos da
>   pasta, você precisa fazê-lo dentro do bash com as ferramentas de linha
>   de comando. Somente arquivos que estão em /mnt/* são realmente
>   manipuláveis no Windows Explorer. - https://superuser.com/a/1111092

É possível fazer login remoto por meio de **SSH**

Respondendo a questão, os arquivos podem ser vistos dentro da pasta *Packages*, que fica dentro do *AppData* do diretório de usuário. E isto foi modificado recentemente, Windows 10 + WSL - Ubuntu 18.

```
C:\Users\NomedoUsuario\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\
```